# Can only install either of two packages with "python setup.py develop", other uninstalled

Tags: python, setuptools

From my development directories, I install each package one at a time using

```
python setup.py develop
```

I test an import from a cmd prompt and it works for that package.

After switching to the other development directory and doing the same

```
python setup.py develop
```

I can then import this second package, but not the one that just worked -- it no longer does.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Shutting all my cmd windows and starting fresh resolved the issue.

At one point I checked and it turned out that a fresh cmd window had different import results compared to the cmd window I was doing all the setup in. All my tests for functionality had been in fresh cmd windows. I had changed some path stuff around recently and left cmd windows open, and I suspect I was setting up in an older window with non-current path information.

Specifically, I had removed entries from my PYTHONPATH environment variable, since I wanted to use setup develop instead. It seems setup is sensitive to PYTHONPATH, configuring things different for items on the path vs off. Still interesting that both would work, but just undo each other.